# Why do I get an error when I try to load ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run:

```
library("ggplot2")
```

I get the error below:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 object ‘enexprs’ is not exported by 'namespace:rlang'
```

In addition:

```
 Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You can try updating your packages or reinstalling both `rlang` and `ggplot2` if it's still not working

Comment: A simple way of doing this is `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest version of rlang to solve this error.